# Empty values do not show up again after filtering from angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angular-datatables

I am filtering by column on my datatable in angularjs. My datataset is as follows:

```
{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
{name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
{name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
{name:'Johnny'}
```

When I filter based on `Phone Number`, lets say "55", I get the following 2 results:

```
{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
{name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'}
```

But when I clear the text box, I do not get all the 4 back, but instead get the 3 with non-null phone numbers:

```
{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
{name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
{name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'}
```

The one with the null phone number does not show up.

Whole code can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1r2nGqOhXQSCSIrILY3Z?p=preview

Additional info: I even tried replacing the empty string in the input text box with null with a JS function in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens due to the absence of `phone` property, try [this solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDRopMx3igebmvsNI0sw?p=preview):

```
<tr ng-init='friendObj.phone = friendObj.phone || ""' ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ng-change` directive:

```
<label>Phone only 
   <input ng-model="search.phone"
          ng-change="searchChange()">
</label><br>
```

And have it delete the property when the model is empty:

```
$scope.searchChange = function() {
    if (!$scope.search.phone) delete $scope.search.phone; 
}
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/B48PRrvNXzb8d52tPTk1?p=preview)